# Ubuntu Transfer from external hard disk

Tags: transfer

How I can transfer ubuntu from an external hard disk to my laptop?
I have Windows also installed.
Thank you for answers.

Comment: Hi & Welcome to **AU**. Can you be more specific and descriptive as to what are you trying to achieve exactly..?? What do you mean by external disk to laptop transfer? is it just the ISO file or anything else... This will help us to assist you better. :)

Comment: I think that the easiest way (for beginners) is to create an ext4 (or ext3) partition on your laptop and using a live CD, you can copy all the content from the Ubuntu partition on your HDD to the new partition and then boot again from the CD and choose to repair the current version.

Comment: I mean that I have an Ubuntu partition on an external hard drive. I want to copy the complete system to a partition of my laptop.
I already use Windows on my laptop.

Comment: **Tank you** for this answers ;) i have now done and it's good. Thanks.